# Tkinter slideshow with buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i want to code a slideshow that changes the image after a button is pressed. I also want to be able to change images in both directions.

Obviously i found some code that somewhat fits but not exactly how i want it.
class ImageViewer(tk.Tk):

```
import glob
import tkinter as tki
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class ImageViewer(tki.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        """Create the ImageViewer."""
        # Attributes for the image handling.
        self.image_names=glob.glob('/home/pi/Images/*.png')
        self.index = 0
        self.photo = None
        #Button init
        btn= tki.Button(self.root,text="NextPic",command=self.show_image)
        btn.grid(sticky = tki.S)
        # We'll use a Label to display the images.

        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        self.label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        # Delay should be in ms.
        self.delay = 1000*2.5
        # Display the first image.
        self.show_image()

    def show_image(self):
        """Display an image."""
        # We need to use PIL.Image to open png files, since
        # tkinter's PhotoImage only reads gif and pgm/ppm files.
        image = Image.open(self.image_names[index])
        # We need to keep a reference to the image!
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.index += 1
        if self.index == len(self.image_names):
            self.index = 0
        # Set the image
        self.label['image'] = self.photo
        # Tell tkinter we want this method to be called again after a delay.
        self.after(self.delay, show_image)

root = ImageViewer()
root.mainloop()
```

This is the error:

```
   File "slideshow.py", line 41, in <module>
        root = ImageViewer()
      File "slideshow.py", line 19, in __init__
        btn= tki.Button(self.root, text="Next Pic", command=self.show_image)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1961, in __getattr__
        return getattr(self.tk, attr)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1961, in __getattr__
        return getattr(self.tk, attr)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1961, in __getattr__
        return getattr(self.tk, attr)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The part before Recursion Error is printed many more times so i cut it short.

Comment: thanks for the note. Its fixed now

Comment: that did sadly nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem causing the recursion error is that your `ImageViewer` class subclasses `Tk`, but you never call the `__init__` method of `Tk`. That prevents tkinter from being successfully initialized.

You need to add this as the first statement in `ImageViewer.__init__`:

```
super().__init__()
```

There are many other problems in the code, but they are unrelated to the question you are asking.

Comment: Well thanks that solved the problem. Now the error is AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'root'